# How can I create a "pencil edge" to my object?

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor, shaders

Blender 2.93.1
Cycles with GPU Compute - OptiX Denoising

Light Paths:

- Total 4
- Diffuse 2
- Glossy 2
- Transparency 6
- Transmission 12
- No Clamping
  (I put the light path details here since I'm working with mirrors and translucent materials. Not sure if it will help answer the question or not).

I'm working on some photorealistic product images for wall mirrors right now but I'm having some trouble getting my materials just right (I'm fairly new to blender and 3D design).

I'm trying to create a material that looks like the edges of this mirror:

[image: polished edge mirror black background]

[image: polished edge mirror white background]

The texture of it is slightly exaggerated here, but you can see that it has some translucency and texture to it. The people who make these mirrors take a special grinder/polisher and smooth out the edges of the glass, which makes it a 'polished edge' mirror.

What I've done:

- Created a cube
- Changed dimensions to match mirror specs
- Added a bevel modifier for those slightly rounded edges
- Created different materials for every face of the cube

Now I'm stuck at the pencil edge.

So here is a current render and my current shading nodes.

[image: recent_render]

[image: nodes]

Also, at the corner of the mirror in this recent rendering, the angle is odd where it's transitioning from the z-axis to the x-axis. I'm assuming it's because of the bevel modifier but I'm not sure how to fix that with there being different materials on the object. I think I could deal with that though if I could only get the texture right. I'm not sure why it's showing up so smooth and gray in the render.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I should note: I am going to have to create many different versions of this mirror because there are different sizes with different part numbers and they want images for all of them. This is why I chose to put all the different materials on one cube. I thought it would help me change dimensions to the correct specs more efficiently.

EDIT: This is similar to what I'm looking to do with my glass: [Glass Slab material with green side](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/145419/glass-slab-material-with-green-side)

For some reason when I follow the answer on that post it does not have that green-ish effect on the edges. My edges need to be pretty smooth compared to what my first few pictures show as far as texture goes. To the touch, it almost feels like a matte finished glass.

Answer (score 0):

Relatively new to Blender here as well but maybe it would be easier if you made the edge of the mirror a totally new object... give it some thickness, then apply the material to that.